# How to make apache choose a particular python executable in a virtualenv for django

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I am trying to make apache deliver a django test site that resides in a particular `virtualenv` using the python executable of that `virtualenv`, but it refuses to use anything except the default system python.

I'm working on a server running RedHat.  Apache2 and mod_wsgi are installed along with python 2.6.6.  I have an old site that runs on python 2.4 and django 1.2 that I want to upgrade, but first I need to get it running in those versions in a `virtualenv` setup with python 2.4.  I have every step working EXCEPT I cannot seem to get apache to change the python executable it uses to deliver the django site.  For testing purposes, I'm just using the django default "It Work!" initial page, then intentionally forcing a programming error to have the django error page tell me which python executable is being used to deliver it.

The `VirtualHost` section of my `httpd.conf` file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    #WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/mysite/index.wsgi
    #WSGIDaemonProcess python-path=/home/jnett/python24sites/lib/python2.4/site-packages
    <Location "/python24sitetest">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        PythonOption django.root /python24sitetest
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE python24sitetest.settings
        SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE "/tmp"
        PythonPath "['/var/www/python24sitetest', '/var/www'] + sys.path"
        PythonDebug On
        PythonInterpreter python24sitetest
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried every possible combination/permutation of `WSGIDaemonProcess`, `WSGIPythonPath`, and `WSGIPythonHome` that I can think of, but apache ALWAYS only uses the system default python 2.6 no matter what I try.

How do I force apache to deliver just this particular django site using the particular python executable of the `virtualenv` in which it resides?

[EDIT] I have also tried adding a `WSGIScriptAlias` to `httpd.conf` (commented above), where the file `index.wsgi` is located in the home directory of the django project and contains

```
# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/jnett/python24sites/lib/python2.4/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('//home/jnett/python24sites/projects/mysite')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/jnett/python24sites/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I still get no effect at all.

Comment: You're confusing mod_wsgi and mod_python. `SetHandler python-program` actually makes apache serve the site using mod_python. (PythonSomething directives are for mod_python as well.)

Comment: By the way, do you really need older Python? I kind of doubt there are cases which need only 2.4, and would fail in 2.6. Secondly, if you need this just for development of an upgrade, wouldn't it be okay to do that in development environment using Django's built-in server?

Comment: I don't need such an old python--I have a django site that currently uses such an old python, but I need to get it working as-is before I can start upgrading it.  I've learned from experience to not use the django development server unless it is for the most minimal of tasks.  Too many problems arise when adding extra variables like using a different server.

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration, you're actually using mod_python (which is a bit outdated, and completely different thing from mod_wsgi).

To deploy Django with mod_wsgi, it basically comes down to this, [per Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from alll
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Furthermore, you should set mod_wsgi to daemon mode, to isolate your environments:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup example.com
```

To change Python executable for given enviroment, look into [WSGIPythonExecutable](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonExecutable) directive.

Comment: The problem is, where does this go for RedHat?  `WSGIPythonPath` cannot go inside `VirtualHost`, which is where I need it to happen and I would need a different one for each `virtualenv`'s site.

Answer (score 2):

Both mod_python and mod_wsgi are compiled for a specific Python version. If they are compiled for Python 2.6, you cannot force them to use a Python 2.4 installation

What you would need to do is uninstall both mod_python and mod_wsgi from your operating system and then compile mod_wsgi from source code against Python 2.4 yourself and install that.

Do note that latest mod_wsgi versions may no longer compile with such an old Python version. If the latest mod_wsgi version doesn't compile or run properly, go back and try source code for mod_wsgi version 3.5 instead.

Comment: If mod_wsgi can only be compiled only against one particular python version, does that imply that installing a separate mod_wsgi for each virtualenv is the correct manner in which to run multiple sites from the same server?

Comment: Because Apache can only load one of the Apache modules at the same time were you to have more than one compiled for different Python versions, then not really. You could use mod_wsgi-express and so pip install mod_wsgi into search separate Python virtual environment, but you would then need Apache or nginx to proxy to the separate instances of mod_wsgi-express then run up against the different Python virtual environments. This works as the instances for each version are in different processes.